# How to fuzzy search a git repository for content that once existed?

Tags: search, git, fzf

I love [fzf.vim](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) for file content searching within vim. But how could I use that to search for content that was once in a git repository's files?

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928584/how-to-grep-search-committed-code-in-the-git-history) has basically two interesting answers, I would say, but they are for searching on the commandline:

Using pickaxe:

```
git log -SFoo -- path_containing_change
git log -SFoo --since=2009.1.1 --until=2010.1.1 -- path_containing_change
```

And using git grep:

```
git grep <regexp> $(git rev-list --all)
git grep <regexp> $(git rev-list <rev1>..<rev2>)
```

Fzf.vim suggests a GGrep command in its README, which just searches the currently checked in versions of all files (i.e. same as `:Rg`).

So I tried plugging the same `git grep $(git rev-list)` command into that:

```
command! -bang -nargs=* GGrep
  \ call fzf#vim#grep(
  \   'git grep --line-number -- '.shellescape(<q-args>).' $(git rev-list --all)', 0,
  \   fzf#vim#with_preview({'dir': systemlist('git rev-parse --show-toplevel')[0]}), <bang>0)
```

Although that search seems to work fine, when I press enter I would want it to open fugitive showing the commit of the file. Currently it opens a new empty buffer with a name such as `a8b7d22ef54:some/file.txt`, which is really not helpful. I wasn't able to find anything in fzf's documentation that shows how to customize the opening of the file.

The command I hacked together probably also doesn't work for large repositories, where I would want to search specifically from most recent commits through to older ones. I hope someone has a working configuration they will share for fuzzy searching git repositories.

My current workaround is to use the commandline, and then navigate to the commit specified in [vim-flog](https://github.com/rbong/vim-flog), and then use fugitive's `:Gedit [commit-hash]:[filepath]`.

Comment: I’m not sure this is on topic—it really has nothing to do with vim? I see the bit about wanting to open using fugitive, but the rest seems unrelated. Perhaps narrow the question to « how can I open a hash with fugitive »? To which the answer is probably `:Gedit` and variants; use `vim -c` if you want to run this at the command-line

Comment: Ah, perhaps I was unclear; my question has everything to do with vim, will edit. I don't want to be quite so narrow in specifying a solution, because it would also be perfectly valid to say 'use these fugitive / fzf bindings' or even 'use plugin X'.

Comment: so, I'm not looking for a commandline solution at all, I was just linking to the best equivalent that I currently have, which uses the commandline and is extremely inefficient in terms of keystrokes.

Comment: I’m sorry, I still don’t see the full picture—are you asking how to use fzf to do the search? Or how to use the fzf results with fugitive? Or...? It seems like *search works fine*, so you just need to make fzf execute `Gedit` on the result? (Also, the title might need work: *how would you do* is a recipe for opinions.)

Comment: alright, I just found fzf's sink (`:help fzf#run`) options through some other user's issue. Hang tight and I will soon have an answer that at least somewhat works. I still hope someone else has a streamlined and robust solution I can take over though.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I'd be curious!

Comment: Something like `:call fzf#run(fzf#wrap(#{source: 'git log -G'.shellescape(<q-args>), sink: ':Gedit'}))` might work; you might need slightly more post-processing on the `sink`.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across another solution for fzf.vim which was introduced with [this commit](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/commit/ca542801a1b4cda814aec3606d3e3779f6c2e9f7).
It doesn't seem to be documented apart from this commit message:

> [[B]Commits] Support arguments for git-log
>
> Add support for command arguments that are passed to git-log (e.g.
>
> :Commits -S foo -3).

It however can be used this way:

```
Commits
Commits!
Commits -S foo
Commits! -S foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same question and couldn't find a solution with fzf.vim myself, but there seems to be a solution using `search_log_content_file` as part of the [advanced-git-search.nvim](https://github.com/aaronhallaert/advanced-git-search.nvim#5-search_log_content_file) plugin (which is however based on Telescope):

> Advanced Git Search
>
> Opens a Telescope window with a list of git commits that changed the current >file (renames included).
>
> Grep behavior: filter on added, updated or removed code (log content: -G option in git).

It is invoked using:

```
:Telescope advanced_git_search search_log_content_file
```

which opens a fuzzy finder window in which you can search for content.

There is even a small demo [here](https://youtu.be/bO0uYLlHtYo?t=69)